# How to change cursor in custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cursor, browser

Here is my custom `WebBrowser control`.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RunescapeClient : WebBrowser
{
  private const string RUNESCAPE_CLIENT_URL = "http://oldschool33.runescape.com/j1";

public RunescapeClient()
{
    ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
    ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = false;
    AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
    Navigate(RUNESCAPE_CLIENT_URL);
}

protected override void OnDocumentCompleted(WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Document != null && ValidClientUrl(e.Url.ToString()))
    {
        HtmlElement tableElement = Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")[1];
        tableElement.InnerText = string.Empty;
    }
}

private static bool ValidClientUrl(string url)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(url, @"http://oldschool\d{1,2}.runescape.com/j1");
}
}
```

How can I change the `cursor` for this `control` to my `embedded .ico`. I googled and couldn't find anything for `custom controls`.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is to change the ICON, not the (mouse)-CURSOR?

Comment: How can I replace the DEFAULT cursor with a custom .ICO file in my resource as the WebBrowser control only has the default icon available.

Answer (score 0):

The cursor is always changed by the `Cursor` property. It doesn't matter if you have a custom control.

Try this:

```
Icon ico = new Icon(@"C:\temp\someIcon.ico");
this.Cursor = new Cursor(ico.Handle);
```

The static class `System.Windows.Forms.Cursors` contains all system cursors.
To switch back to the default system cursor, use this:

```
this.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
```

Comment: "The WebBrowser control does not support the Cursor property." How would I get around this?

Comment: My bad. `this` is the form that contains your WebBrowser control. So you may use `this.TopLevelControl.Cursor` to change the cursor.

Comment: I appreciate your help; however, it does not work. When the mouse is outside the WebBrowser control, it works, however, when the mouse is placed on the WebBrowser control, it switches back to the Default cursor. **EDIT: this.TopLevelControl.Cursor does not as well.